# Adding UIPickerView as superview to TableView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uipickerview

So in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` im using `[self.tableView addSubview:picker]` to add a picker into superview of the table.

The problem is, that I can't select any row in the pickerView, because any finger swipe over the picker makes the tableView scroll/bounce, together with the picker, but the picker itself does not scroll its selection. The pickerView is basically unusable like this. Is there any other way of subviewing the picker, so that it really is in front of the TableView, and doesn't scroll with it?

Note that `[self.view addSubview:picker]` isn't working as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add it to your `view`:

```
[self.view addSubview:picker];
```

If `view` is not your `tableView`...

Updated:

Then I suggest to create `UIView`, on it put your `UITableView` and then put `UIView` with `backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];` and finally put `UIPickerView`.

Answer (score 0):

Add it to your navigation controller view and everything will work fine :D